# Get Product Collecton by category with filters in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, collection, category-products

I need to filter category product collection with Instock items and only simple products.

I have used below code to implement it.But the out of stock products also fetching with the collection.

```
class CategoryData extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{  
 protected $categoryFactory;
  public function __construct(
     \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
     \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
     ){ 
       $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
       parent::__construct($context);
     } 
  public function getSimilarCollection($productId)
   {
        $categoryId = 10;
        $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId); 
        $categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)    
                                 ->setPageSize(6);
         return $categoryProducts;
    } 
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to filter the above collection with instock items. Thanks

Comment: Try to add code before return statement $categoryProducts->joinField(
        'qty', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left'
    );

Comment: @user55548, can you pls update to my question

Comment: I have added complete code in answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply joinField for get only instock items :

### Method 1 :

```
$category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId); 
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
                         ->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id', 'is_in_stock=1')
                         ->setPageSize(6);
```

### Method 2 :

```
$category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId); 
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);    
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', 1)
                         ->setPageSize(6);
```

Comment: hi @Rohan, still this filters the collection with out of stock items

Comment: Did you clean cache? Check once again. It's working.

Comment: yes cleared cache and checked it.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: can we filter with best seller like order qty?

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete code.

```
$categoryId = 10;
$category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId); 
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)                                
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                    ->setPageSize(6);
$categoryProducts->joinField( 'qty', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left' );

return $categoryProducts;
```

Please let me know if it any issue.

Comment: hi, i can still see the collection is fetching the out of stock item after clearing cache also. that product is configurable product. so, can we apply other filter to filter only simple products

Comment: For configurable you need to check child product status.