# Unable to get not visible products after applying category filter magento2

Tags: magento2, product-collection, grouped-products

I am trying to get Child products from collection after applying category filter but unable to get all products (want to get all products including `Not Visible Individually`  products

```
            $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($value);
            $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
            $ids = $collection->getAllIds();
```

Now in $ids i get only parent products i need all products parent and there child at same time.

Child and parent products all are enabled but can't access child

Comment: Can you describe, what you are trying to do?

Comment: i am just trying to get child product of group product after applying filter of a category  to the product collection

Comment: is the attribute of the category `is anchor` set to yes or no ?

Comment: category  anchor is set to yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
  
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function getProductCollectionByCategories($ids)
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $ids]);
    return $collection;
}
```

To get all product ids:

```
$collection = $this->getProductCollectionByCategories([$value]);
$ids = $collection->getAllIds();
```

Comment: Also you can refer [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/255773)

Comment: thanks for the answer that's what i was looking for mate